# SQL запрос на возражение с LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаюсь сделать запрос на возражение, с использованием LEFT JOIN. Правильно ли я понимаю, что такой запрос будет работать только, если данные в БД с одной страницы будет NULL, когда с таблицы слева будут все таблицы.

Реализовал запрос на возражение с использование предиката IN. Вот, если ли у Вас какой-то совет как это можно сделать с LEFT JOIN или все зависит от данных только.

```
select first_name,last_name
from
  user1
  join employee using (user_id)
  join team_object using (team_id)
  join work1 using (team_object_id)
where
  (start_date,completion_date) not in (
    select start_date, completion_date
    from work1
    where
      start_date between current_date - 30 and current_date
      or
      completion_date between current_date - 30 and current_date
  )
```

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, условие задачи, которую вы решаете. возможно, тут можно обойтись без подзапроса

Comment: @nörbörnën Мне не важно, если подзапрос или нету.. Я, хочу выбрать ФИО людей, которые не входят в данный мой промежуток дат

Comment: @nörbörnën То есть, не работали в прошлом месяце, если кратко

Comment: Что такое возражение?

Comment: @vp_arth такое ощущение. что это гугло-перевод какой-то

Comment: я бы написал where not exists и пусть СУБД сама дальше разбирается

Comment: @vp_arth, teran  Это как противоположные тем события, которые произошли. К примеру допустим, если работники которые работали в этом месяце, а возражение этому будет, кто не работал в этом месяце

Comment: @vp_arth У меня уже 2 варианта реализованных с `exists` и `in` есть. Хочу с использованием `LEFT JOIN` Посмотреть как работает и думает)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю так то так проверьте на своем примере

```
select first_name,last_name
from
  user1
  join employee using (user_id)
  join team_object using (team_id)
  Left join work1 
 On work1.team_object_id = team_object.team_object_id
  And not (
      start_date between current_date - 30 and current_date
      or
      completion_date between current_date - 30 and current_date
  )
Where work1.team_object_id is not null
```

Comment: Как только убираю `LEFT` из `JOIN`сразу корректно выдает, а с ним выдает все данные как без будто `not` не видит

Comment: А щя подправлю тогда

Comment: Вам не нужен left в вашем случае либо left но с проверкой на id что эквивалентно inner join

Comment: Понятно, благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
select first_name,last_name
from
  user1
  join employee using (user_id)
  left join team_object using (team_id)
  left join work1 using (team_object_id)
where work1.id is null -- подходящий work не найден
AND -- отсекаем неподходящие work
  (start_date between current_date - 30 and current_date
  or
  completion_date between current_date - 30 and current_date)
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Учту для будущих проектов